# First and last record of a date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I want to generate a user login report where I want to show the users first login time and last logout time for each day of a month. The table of UserLoginSession is as below

| UserLoginSessionId | UserId | LoginDate | LogoutDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1310582 | 59 | 2021-04-30 15:49:54.997 | 2021-04-30 17:31:18.833 |
| 1310579 | 59 | 2021-04-30 14:53:51.460 | NULL |
| 1310575 | 59 | 2021-04-30 14:39:45.937 | 2021-04-30 14:52:23.150 |
| 1310569 | 59 | 2021-04-30 13:49:36.137 | NULL |
| 1300484 | 59 | 2021-04-28 15:17:48.837 | NULL |
| 1300478 | 59 | 2021-04-28 12:17:50.200 | NULL |
| 1300466 | 59 | 2021-04-28 04:23:48.697 | 2021-04-28 07:45:11.937 |
| 1299527 | 2466 | 2021-04-18 06:07:51.070 | NULL |
| 1299489 | 2466 | 2021-04-17 06:57:01.860 | 2021-04-17 06:57:28.260 |
| 1299449 | 2466 | 2021-04-16 10:16:54.730 | NULL |
| 1299442 | 2466 | 2021-04-16 10:08:30.187 | 2021-04-16 10:36:05.963 |
| 1299422 | 2466 | 2021-04-16 07:30:32.990 | 2021-04-16 10:15:25.777 |

The output report should be like below where if the logout date is null, it should take the end time of the day

| UserId | LoginDate | LogoutDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 59 | 2021-04-30 13:49:36.137 | 2021-04-30 17:31:18.833 |
| 59 | 2021-04-28 04:23:48.697 | 2021-04-28 23:59:59.000 |
| 2466 | 2021-04-18 06:07:51.070 | 2021-04-18 23:59:59.000 |
| 2466 | 2021-04-17 06:57:01.860 | 2021-04-17 06:57:28.260 |
| 2466 | 2021-04-16 07:30:32.990 | 2021-04-16 23:59:59.000 |

I have tried the below query but it is giving me output in separate rows.

```
select  UserId, case when rn1 = 1 then LoginDate end as [LoginDate], case when rn2 = 1 then LogoutDate end as [LogoutDate]
from    (
        select  
        row_number() over (partition by U.UserId, convert(date,s.LoginDate) order by s.LoginDate) as rn1, 
        row_number() over (partition by U.UserId, convert(date,s.LogoutDate) order by s.LogoutDate desc) as rn2, 
        S.*
        from    UserLoginSession S
        where S.CreatedAt between @StartDate and @EndDate
        ) as SubQueryTable
where rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1
```

I am not able to bring both the records in a single row in the query. How can I modify my query to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Where does logout date for 59 of 2021-04-30 17:31:18.833 come from? I don't see that in anywhere your input data.

Comment: "it should take the end time of the day" - but your example doesn't. It ignores anything that happens *during* the last second, when the milliseconds value isn't 000. This is often a cause of subtle errors, and why I'd usually recommend modelling time periods as a half-closed interval, where the end point is *exclusive*. Computing such end points also tends to be simpler.

Comment: Why not use `MIN` and `MAX`?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that logout date is the first record in my input table with userloginsessionid - 1310582 which is the last time user logged out for that date

Comment: I swear that wasn't there before.... anyway..... sounds like you just need to add a day column and group on that and use MAX/MIN as already mentioned.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah I would not like to miss out those records as well which have milliseconds in the end. Should consider them as well !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MIN and MAX and hacking around when LogoutDate is NULL:

```
SELECT UserId, CONVERT(date, LoginDate), MIN(LoginDate), ISNULL(MAX(LogoutDate), DATEADD(MS, -2, CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(D, 1, CONVERT(date, LoginDate)))))
FROM UserLoginSession
GROUP BY UserId,CONVERT(date, LoginDate)
ORDER BY UserId,CONVERT(date, LoginDate)
```

Comment: You could refactor `CONVERT(date, LoginDate)` into a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`, saves having to repeat it 4 times